# array out of bound exception while deleting element from an array

Tags: java, arrays

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class SearchDeletion2 {
private int a[] ;
SearchDeletion2(int size){
 a =new int[size];
}
public void set(int index,int elem){
    a[index]=elem;
}
public int get(int index){
    return a[index];
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    SearchDeletion2 arr = new SearchDeletion2(10);
    arr.set(0,33);
    arr.set(1,22);
    arr.set(2,11);
    arr.set(3,99);
    arr.set(4,66);
    arr.set(5,44);
    arr.set(6,77);
    arr.set(7,88);
    arr.set(8,55);
    arr.set(9,112);
    int i;
    int l=10;
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    int r = sc.nextInt();
    for(i=0;i<l;i++)
        if(arr.get(i)==r)
            break;
    System.out.println(i);
    for(int k =i;k<l;k++)

        arr.set(k,arr.get(k+1));

         l--;
         System.out.println(l);
        for (int o=0;o<l;o++) 
             System.out.println(arr.get(o));


        }
}
```

while running this program i am getting array out of bond exception,tried a lot to find out the reason but couldn't .
112
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 10
    at SearchDeletion2.get(SearchDeletion2.java:12)
    at SearchDeletion2.main(SearchDeletion2.java:36)
9

but this below same program from my book runs fine.i couldn't get the diffrence

```
class LowArray1
{
private long[] a; // ref to array a
//--------------------------------------------------------------
public LowArray1(int size) // constructor
{ a = new long[size]; } // create array
//--------------------------------------------------------------
public void setElem(int index, long value) // set value
{ a[index] = value; }
//--------------------------------------------------------------
public long getElem(int index) // get value
{ return a[index]; }
//--------------------------------------------------------------
} // end class LowArray
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
class LowArrayApp1
{
public static void main(String[] args)
{
LowArray1 arr; // reference
arr = new LowArray1(100); // create LowArray object
int nElems = 0; // number of items in array
int j; // loop variable
arr.setElem(0, 77); // insert 10 items
arr.setElem(1, 99);
arr.setElem(2, 44);
arr.setElem(3, 55);
arr.setElem(4, 22);
arr.setElem(5, 88);
arr.setElem(6, 11);
arr.setElem(7, 00);
arr.setElem(8, 66);
arr.setElem(9, 33);
nElems = 10; // now 10 items in array
for(j=0; j<nElems; j++) // display items
System.out.print(arr.getElem(j) + " ");
System.out.println("");
int searchKey = 26; // search for data item
for(j=0; j<nElems; j++) // for each element,
if(arr.getElem(j) == searchKey) // found item?
break;
if(j == nElems) // no
System.out.println("Can’t find" + searchKey);
else // yes
System.out.println("Found " + searchKey);
//delete value 55
for(j=0; j<nElems; j++) // look for it
if(arr.getElem(j) == 55)
break;
for(int k=j; k<nElems; k++) // higher ones down
    arr.setElem(k, arr.getElem(k+1) );
    nElems--; // decrement size
    for(j=0; j<nElems; j++) // display items
    System.out.print( arr.getElem(j) +" ");
    System.out.println(" ");
    } // end main()
    } // end class LowArrayApp
```

Comment: I can't understand your problem beside the ArrayIndexOutOfBounds, and you should put the stacktrace.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
for(int k =i;k<l;k++)

    arr.set(k,arr.get(k+1));
```

When `k = l - 1 = 10 - 1 = 9`, `k+1 = 10`, so `arr.get(k+1)` is out of bounds.

The main difference between the two pieces of code is that in the first, you initialize the size of the array to 10 :

```
SearchDeletion2 arr = new SearchDeletion2(10);
```

While in the second you initialize it to 100 :

```
arr = new LowArray1(100);
```

Therefore, in the second piece of code, the index `10` is valid, while in the first piece of code it isn't.

Comment: for(int k=j; k<nElems; k++) // higher ones down
    arr.setElem(k, arr.getElem(k+1) );
    nElems--; // decrement size
    for(j=0; j<nElems; j++) // display items
    System.out.print( arr.getElem(j) +" ");
    System.out.println(" ");

Comment: @sdvadsa Please don't put code in a comment. It's very hard to read. You can add it to your question instead.

Comment: i put in question check